# Mudar Background do menu da ActionBar

Tags: android

Ola,
existe alguma maneira de mudar no XML a cor de background do menu de opções que aparece na `ActionBar`?

Comment: Você está utilizando já a nova `Toolbar` ou mesmo à opção antiga para a `ActionBar`?

Comment: @PauloRodrigues não sei bem responder a tua pergunta, acho que tou a utilizar antiga, como vejo isso?..tou a utilizar a API 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você tem duas opções:

1) Se você está utilizando a `Toolbar` (se não está utilizando, recomendo), você pode inserir componentes em sua toolbar e mexer como você quiser. Por exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:theme="@style/SeuTema"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/img_exemplo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/sua_cor"
        android:src="@drawable/seu_icone" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

2) Se você não está utilizando a `Toolbar`, existe uma maneira de "hackea-la" [de acordo com esse post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944244/change-the-background-color-of-the-options-menu) , e irei resumi-lo para você:

Os itens do menu tem vários estilos, maneiras, aparências etc. em diversos devices de diferentes fabricantes. Não existe uma maneira documentada para fazer isto. Existem algumas opções listadas no post, mas estão longe de serem as opções ideais para a resolução deste problema, e ainda por cima não funciona em todos os aparelhos.

Se você realmente precisa ter um background para seus itens do menu, sugiro que estude a implementação da `Toolbar` em seu projeto para não ter que enfrentar nenhuma "surpresa" indesejada. Se for o caso, [siga a documentação oficial de como implementa-las](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) e existem alguns artigos que podem te ajudar bastante nisso.

Comment: Obrigada!vou implementar a toolbar @sicachester

Comment: @porthfind boa! Qualquer dúvida poste aqui que nós ajudaremos